# Windows can't find domain name that everyone else can see

Tags: windows, dns

I've configured a DNS server on my home LAN. It serves a few extra domain names, such as `foo`. *Note that `foo` is configured to return 404s for all requests.* (I haven't gotten to getting it to do what I want it to do.) Also, *note that `foo` is a single-level domain name*, i.e., `foo.` is the FQDN. Hopefully obvious, this is not a name that I expect to resolve anywhere but my home network.

A lone Windows machine on the network seems to be failing DNS requests — I have no idea why.

Network topology, just for reference:

```
^ out to Comcast
|
* Comcast modem
|
+-* 10.1.10.2, a server, hosting a webserver and a DNS server.
+-* 10.1.10.3/192.168.2.1, a wireless router.
  |
(via WiFi)
  |
  +-* an Android phone
  +-* a Windows laptop.
  +-* a Linux laptop.
```

The wireless router is configured to use 10.1.10.2 for DNS. However, it sends out 192.168.2.1 as the DNS server in its DHCP response (verified with Wireshark).

The Android phone, if asked to do `http://foo/` in Chrome, gets the 404. (Which is correct.)

The Windows machine, if asked to do the same in Chrome, fails, with a "Oops! Google Chrome could not find" page. Using `nslookup` on the machine, and giving it `foo` at the prompt, it appears to be unable to find `foo`. It claims to be using 192.168.2.1 as a DNS server. If I `nslookup` `foo.` (note the dot), I get the right IP address back. If I request `http://10.1.10.2`, I get the 404.

On the Linux machine, a `dig @10.1.10.2 foo` gives the right response. Additionally, `dig @192.168.2.1 foo` also gives the correct result.

What the heck is going on? Why is the Windows machine returning not found for DNS responses, whereas all the other machines seem to get the right answer?

**Edit:** I have Python on the Windows machine. I actually have two domains, `foo` and `bar`. Python's `socket.gethostbyname` can see `foo`, but not `bar`. (They're being served by the same DNS server mind you — the records are identical save for the name.) `nslookup` can't see squat, except the one with dot. Nothing works in Chrome.

Comment: Try booting in Safe Mode with networking support, then access the domain, if it works, its something installed on your Windows system causing the issue.

Comment: If it works with the trailing dot, then it is because Windows does not think `foo` is a fully qualified domain, and appends its own primary suffix - eq it is looking for `foo.local`.  The dot lets Windows know it is fqdn.  Is the domain really a single level, it contains no dots?

Comment: Too vague, not really helpful. Why should (s)he do that ? Please explain.

Comment: Yes, the domain is actually a single level, e.g., just `foo`. Obviously, this DNS server is not serving to the Internet, and is only intended to work here, on my home network.

Comment: is WINS running?